# how to dynamically add combobox in windows forms(C#) and bound it to a column of a table in sql database

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

My windows form has an ADD button which adds a combo box to the form after each click. The problem is, i am not able to bind it to a table column at run time. Using an existing databinding source selects the same value in all the combo boxes. I am coding in C#

here is the sample code :

```
ComboBox ocbNext = new ComboBox();
//HAVE set the rest of the properties right, the problem is with the databinding
ocbNext.DataSource = this.dummysubjectBindingSource;
ocbNext.DisplayMember = "sub_name";
ocbNext.ValueMember = "sub_name";
this.Controls.Add(ocbNext);
```

Comment: Looks like you already got the first part of the question answered. For the second part, it should be fairly easy to implement. Let's see what you got so far...

Comment: hey tzup
the problem is with ocbNext.DataSource = this.dummysubjectBindingSource;

its the same databindingsource that i added for the statically present combo box, when i use the same databinding source for the dynamically added cmbo box, the problem starts.

the initial data bindingsource was added via the wizard...i dnt knw how to add one dynamically

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I added a **DataSet** to the solution and droped the *Employees* table (from *Northwind*) in the designer, which automatically created the **employeesBindingSource**. I dropped a combobox and a button on the Form and I set the **DataSource** and **DataMember** of the combo. Then I handled some events:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.employeesTableAdapter.Fill(this.dS.Employees);
    }

    private int _i = 0;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox combo = new ComboBox();
        combo.DataSource = this.employeesBindingSource;
        combo.DisplayMember = this.dS.Tables[0].Columns[++_i].ColumnName;
        combo.Location = new Point(comboBox1.Location.X, comboBox1.Location.Y + comboBox1.Height * _i);
        this.Controls.Add(combo);
    }
```

So on each click, a new combo is added onto the form dynamically right under the previous combo. The combo is also bound to  the next column in the Employees table (no boundary checks however).

As you can see, this is pretty easy stuff. Hope this helps.

---

Okay, so here is a variation of the code that could help you with that other question you asked in the comments of this answer.

It assumes you have a **Form** with a button and a *DataSet* with table *Employees*. On button click it creates a combo, and fills it with data (the *Name* column of *Employees*). Each time you add a combo, it gets its own copy of the data (this is important to be able to remove items from one combo at a time). Then, every time you select a value in the combo, the combo is disabled and the other combos don't have that selected value in their list.

```
  private int _i = 0;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet dataS = dS.Clone();
        this.employeesTableAdapter.Fill((DS.EmployeesDataTable)dataS.Tables[0]);
        BindingSource bindSource = new BindingSource(dataS, "Employees");

        ComboBox combo = new ComboBox();
        combo.Name = this.dS.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName + (++_i).ToString();
        combo.DataSource = bindSource;
        combo.DisplayMember =  this.dS.Tables[0].Columns[1].ColumnName; //This column is the Name of Employee
        combo.Location = new Point(button1.Location.X, button1.Location.Y + combo.Height * _i);
        combo.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
        this.Controls.Add(combo);
    }

    private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is ComboBox && ctrl != sender && ctrl.Enabled)
            {
                ((BindingSource)((ComboBox)ctrl).DataSource).RemoveAt(((ComboBox)sender).SelectedIndex);
            }
        }
        ((ComboBox)sender).Enabled = false;
    }
```

This is pretty close to what you require, or easily adaptable to meet your expectations. Enjoy and please select an answer as the accepted one. Thanks!

Comment: thnx tzup...it really ws simple n it hlpd.
Cn u pls let me knw hw to mk sure the user selects a different value for each combo box?? i mean is there a way to disable the already selected values???

Comment: Hi Raghav, please see the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Fill the combobox with strings:

```
this.comboBox1.Items.Add("Syed");
this.comboBox1.Items.Add("Baqar");
```

Option 2: Fill the combobox with an array of strings:

```
this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] { "Syed", "Baqar" });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add controls to the parent window first, and then set the data source.

```
ComboBox ocbNext = new ComboBox();
this.Controls.Add(ocbNext);
ocbNext.DisplayMember = "sub_name";
ocbNext.ValueMember = "sub_name";
ocbNext.DataSource = this.dummysubjectBindingSource;
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be fine if you create a new local ComboBox variable in the clickevent. If you use a global variable for the ComboBox this might explain your problems. But without a sample how you're doing it's hard to see what's really happening, so think this is just a rough guess