# Manually initiallized combobox won't show up when called in c#

Tags: c#, combobox

I just created a form with many combobox but they only use the same data. At the first time, I load the data for every click on the radiobutton, but it takes some time and it's so annoying. So instead of loading the combobox everytime I click a radiobutton, I want it to load just one time when the app start.

The code below is to create the global combobox which can be called anywhere in the form.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       //code to get the requester below
       public List<XMLSoccerCOM.Team> all_team = requester.GetAllTeams();
       public List<XMLSoccerCOM.League> all_league = requester.GetAllLeagues();

       public ComboBox combo_team = new ComboBox();   //global combo_team
       public ComboBox combo_league = new ComboBox();  //global combo_league

       //the rest of the code
    }
```

And inside of this form, there's a init method:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        his_combobox.Visible = false; //I hide everything so that I can show them when click on the radiobutton
        foreach (XMLSoccerCOM.Team te in all_team)    //This one for the first combobox
        {
            combo_team.Items.Add(te.Name.ToString());
        }
        foreach (XMLSoccerCOM.League le in all_league)  //And the 2nd as well
        {
           combo_league.Items.Add(le.Name.ToString());
        }
    }
```

So looks like it's done, I just need to assign it whenever I want. In the radiobutton checkchange event I make it:

```
    private void history_league_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        his_combobox = combo_league;   // Assign the global league combobox to a local combobox.

        his_odds_label.Text = "Choose the league:"; //This label is next to the his_combobox
        his_odds_label.Visible = true;
        his_combobox.Visible = true;   //Show them if it's hidden by another radiobutton

    }

    private void history_team_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        his_combobox = combo_team;   // Assign the global team combobox to a local combobox.

        his_odds_label.Text = "Choose the team:"; //This label is next to the his_combobox
        his_odds_label.Visible = true;
        his_combobox.Visible = true;   //Show them if it's hidden by another radiobutton

    }
```

But it's not showing up when I Ctrl+F5, only the label shows up, the his_combobox doesn't, just like it's never be there.

Feel free to ask for more information. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have a look here, maybe it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152705/how-to-dynamically-add-combobox-in-windows-formsc-and-bound-it-to-a-column-of | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721436/binding-xml-to-combobox

Answer (score 0):

assigning datasource is critical.

`his_combobox.DataSource = combo_league.DataSource;`

but i would go further simpler approach something like this.

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var checkbox = (CheckBox) sender;
        comboBox1.DataSource = checkbox.Checked ? all_team : all_league;
        comboBox1.Visible = true;
    }
```

by this approch you dont have to create additional combo boxes, but it is up to your need.

**EDIT:**
In my example i had all_team and all_league as string type but you can adjust that according to your properties.

```
public List<String> all_team = new List<string>
    {
        "Team A",
        "Team B"
    };

    public List<String> all_league = new List<string>
    {
        "League a",
        "League b"
    };

    public ComboBox combo_team = new ComboBox();   //global combo_team
    public ComboBox combo_league = new ComboBox();  //global combo_league

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.Visible = false;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method 1
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var checkbox = (CheckBox) sender;
        comboBox1.DataSource = checkbox.Checked ? all_team : all_league;
        comboBox1.Visible = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method2
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        combo_league.DataSource = all_league;
        combo_team.DataSource = all_team;
        var checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;

        comboBox1.DataSource = checkbox.Checked?combo_league.DataSource:combo_team.DataSource;
        comboBox1.Visible = true;

    }
```

Comment: I don't know what is wrong but these didn't work for me.
The first one gives me a empty combobox, the second (shorter way) gives me a combobox of the type, like `XMLSoccerCOM.Team` or `XMLSoccerCOM.League`

Comment: How do I add just one column as datasource? Any suggestion?

Comment: @tranHoai: have you tried adding display member and value member , the values should be your properties. Check this url "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600869/how-to-bind-a-list-to-a-combobox-winforms"

Comment: Thank you, I found my answer from your ideal reply.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out with a few suggestions from Kalyan. I created a global variable:

```
 public List<String> teams = new List<string>();
```

then fill in this list with the items needed (my `all_team` has many columns, that's why it won't show up with `his_combobox.DataSource = combo_team.DataSource;` as he told me)

```
    foreach (XMLSoccerCOM.Team te in all_team)
        {
            teams.Add(te.Name.ToString());
        }
```

Then finally make the `teams` the datasource:

```
   combobox1.DataSource = teams;
```

That's all :) Thank you.